# Rails: validate PayPal email?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, paypal

I'm trying to verify that a seller's email is valid with PayPal.

Is there any way to verify JUST a user's PayPal email? I've been having a really hard time finding an answer to this.

First, I found [this](http://curry.byteally.com/finding-verification-status-of-a-paypal-account-ruby-on-rails-paypal-adaptive-accounts-getverifiedstatus/), which is useful but seems to require a user's first and last name as well as an email address. I've also found [this](https://www.x.com/developers/paypal/documentation-tools/api/addressverify-api-operation-nvp), but this also seems to require extra info.

Isn't there any simple way to check just email? I mean, if you can pay straight to a user's email without any extra info, shouldn't you be able to check if that email is valid?

Comment: I'd require users to also be able to pay with credit card, without having a PP account, like it is possible with website payments standard checkout. Also I don't like the user to see how much money goes to which email address.So ideally I'd like PP Website Payments Standard checkout capability but diverting the payment to different paypal accounts in the background.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the only way to do this is to request extra permissions, and use GetVerifiedStatus from the PayPal API.

Comment: Correct. With one caveat: GetVerifiedStatus will only return a positive response if the account *is* verified. If it's not verified or simply unregistered, it will return the same response (phishers were abusing this functionality to find out which email addresses of their databases had active PayPal accounts)